How to parse a multigraph from a GEXF file/string using graphology and sigmaJS?
I am trying to render a network map using a GEXF file in my application.
I am using ReactJS, with SigmaJS and graphology to handle the graphs. While simple graphs render fine, I am not able to parse graphs with multiple edges between the same nodes.
This is the function I'm using to load a graph (the GEXF string is hidden here):
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Graph from "graphology";
import { SigmaContainer, useLoadGraph } from "@react-sigma/core";
import { parse } from 'graphology-gexf';
const LoadGraph = () => {
        const loadGraph = useLoadGraph();

        useEffect(() => {
                const graph = new Graph({ multi: true });
                parse(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, graph);

                loadGraph(graph);
        }, [loadGraph]);

        return null;
};

I am getting an invalid constructor error: graphology-gexf/parser: invalid Graph constructor.
How do I correctly parse this file/string?

Have you given the good constructor to the SigmaContainer like this :
import { FC } from "react";
import { MultiDirectedGraph } from "graphology";
import { SigmaContainer } from "@react-sigma/core";

export const MultiDirectedGraphView: FC = () => {
  return (
    <SigmaContainer graph={MultiDirectedGraph}>
      <LoadGraph />
    </SigmaContainer>
  );
};

(extract from the FAQ : https://sim51.github.io/react-sigma/docs/faq#how-i-can-create-a-graph-with-parallel-edges-)
